# AppManifest File not found in project

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I started a project DataboundApp1 and coming to competition I cannot find the app manifest file to change settings, tiles etc and cannot find a location for it (It must be somewhere)

Any help to point me in the right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app manifest file is found under the following menus under Solution Explorer

```
> <Name of Project>
> >My Project
> > >App Manifest.xml
> > >WMAppManifest.xml   <------
```